# Need Assistance: Automated Video Editing Using Python

Tags: python, automation, video-editing

I've put together the following code to try and automate the tedious parts of my video editing process. The issue I'm running into is that I run the code in Visual Studio Code, but nothing happens and I receive no errors.

I'm wanting the folder specified to be monitored for unedited/new .mp4 files. When one or multiple are detected, the .mp4 should be formatted in the specified for TikTok upload. (As I would within a video editor, the clip should maintain its aspect ratio within a project setting of 1080x1920/9:16, then a duplicate of the clip is put behind the clip, not maintaining its aspect ratio and have a gaussian blur applied to it. Once the process is done, each edited clip would be put into a separate "edited" folder, or back in the original destination, but renamed as edited.

Here is my current code:

```
import os
import shutil
import ffmpeg
import watchdog
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

# path to monitor
monitor_path = "D:\Downloads\TikTok"
# path to output folder
output_folder = "D:\Downloads\Edited"

# define a function to be called when a new .mp4 file is detected
def detect_new_file(event):
    # input video file path
    input_video = event.src_path
    # output video file name
    output_video_name = os.path.basename(input_video)
    # output video file path
    output_video = os.path.join(output_folder, output_video_name)
    
    # start ffmpeg command
    ffmpeg_command = (
        ffmpeg
        .input(input_video)
        .trim(start_time=0, end_time='-10')
        .filter('scale', size='1080x1920')
        .filter('blur', size=5)
        .overlay(input_video, x=540, y=960)
        .output(output_video, format='mp4')
        .run()
    )
    # move the original file to a new folder
    shutil.move(input_video, os.path.join(monitor_path, "D:\Downloads\OriginalClips"))

# create a handler for the file event
class MP4Handler(watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        if event.src_path.endswith('.mp4'):
            detect_new_file(event)

handler = MP4Handler()

# create a watcher object
watcher = watchdog.observers.Observer()

# start monitoring the folder
watcher.schedule(handler, monitor_path, recursive=True)
watcher.start()

# wait for events
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    watcher.stop()

# close the watcher
watcher.join()
```

Current received error(s):

TypeError: Expected incoming stream(s) to be of one of the following types: ffmpeg.nodes.FilterableStream; got <class 'str'>

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So are you getting or not getting the error? If you do, please add the full traceback of this error to the question, as text, not as an image.

Comment: Apologies- I updated the code after posting the message, but forgot to update the initial post. I am indeed getting an error.

Error: TypeError: Expected incoming stream(s) to be of one of the following types: ffmpeg.nodes.FilterableStream; got <class 'str'>